# Safely cast void* to int

Tags: c++, casting, int, undefined-behavior, void-pointers

If application is compiled to yield a x32 image then depending on architecture integer type may be 16 bits wide, 32s bit wide or anything more than 2 bytes. Size of `void*` will be 4 (on x32 always 4???). This would mean that passing `int` to `void*` is fine, but if it turns out that on a given architecture `void*` is wider than `int` (which is only guaranteed to be at least 2 bytes by the Standard) than in the face of

C Standard n1124 **§** 6.3.2.3 Pointers

> 5 An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as
>   previously specified, the result is implementation-defined, might not
>   be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced
>   type, and might be a trap representation.56)
>
> 6 Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as
>   previously specified, the result is implementation-defined. If the
>   result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is
>   undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any
>   integer type.

casting `void*` to `int` may produce undefined behavior in the following snippet.

```
typedef enum tagENUM
{
    WSO_1,
    WSO_2,
    //...
    WSO_COUNT
} ENUM;

/* I cannot change handler signature because this is callback. I have to cast void*
 * to ENUM however inside */
void handler( int i, int j, void *user_data)
{
    ENUM mOperation;
    mOperation = (ENUM)reinterpret_cast<int>(user_data);
}

// somewhere
handler( 1, 2, (void*)WSO_1);  // UB? We can imagine that someone passes to handler
                               // (void*)WSO_131072 which don't fit into 16 bits
                               // So is there a place opened for UB?
```

If this is correct that possibility for nasal deamons is opened - how do I then write thiss cast safely? Can I use `intptr_t` to make sure the result will fit?

```
void handler( int i, int j, void *user_data)
{
    ENUM mOperation;

uintptr_t p_mOperation = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>( user_data);

if ( p_mOperation > WSO_COUNT ) {
    send_error(conn, 500, http_500_error, "Error: %s", strerror(ERRNO));
    return;
}

mOperation = static_cast<ENUM_WS_OPERATION>( p_mOperation);  // now safe?
```

Comment: `void*` parameters are *not* intended to pass data directly. Just pass your integers *address* instead of the value and you're fine. What you are trying will never work properly and is the main reason for the slow 64 bit adoption in the x86 world.

Comment: I know I can, but my question is about such a case - is there a place for UB? I have to assume someone could passed ANYTHING behind void* - how do I prevent UB?

Comment: the cited part clearly says it's *implementation defined*.

Comment: "Size of `void*` will be 4 always?" - No, not always. Only on platforms with 32-bit memory address space.

Comment: @barakmanos I meant on x32 always it will be 4?

Comment: Well, in that case the answer is yes. Please note, however, that the size of `int` is not guaranteed by the C++ standard to be 4 (I've personally worked with platforms where it was only 2).

Comment: yes, that is what triggered my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it can cause undefined behaviour. If you use `intptr_t` instead then there is no undefined behaviour.

However, usually you can rewrite your code so that the pointer *points to* the intended integer, rather than being intended to be cast to it.

In your second example you have a mishmash. You want to use either use `intptr_t`, or `void *` that points to `int`.   Not `intptr_t *` or `uintptr_t *`.

My preferred solution is that `user_data` always points to the data; and the type of the data being pointed to is determined by the handler being called or another parameter.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. You've got to use `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t` as the parameter type for `handler`.   You can still get UB doing what you are now (because the `uintptr_t` might be wider than the range of legal values for `void *` )

Comment: I cannot change handler signature because this is callback. I have to cast void* to ENUM however inside. Also if uintptr_t is wider it is fine. void* will suit into it

Comment: The thing you're casting to `void *` might not go into `void *`. If you can't change the function then the correct thing to do is to actually pass a pointer; don't do a reinterpret_cast.

Answer (score 0):

This bit:

```
mOperation = (ENUM)reinterpret_cast<int>(user_data);
```

suggests you've lost control of what you're doing already. You're doing a double cast which is always indicative of bad things going on (as if the reinterpret_cast wasn't already indicating that).

It's not clear from this what you're trying to do. Certainly (void*) is an inappropriate cast for passing values that aren't data. It's for passing pointers to arbitrary buffers of data where one hopes the thing at the other end can work out from the data what it needs to do with it.

So this:

```
handler( 1, 2, (void*)WSO_1);
```

is just plain wrong.

However, given that `WSO_1` is in fact an `enum`, and I don't know of any platform where a `void *` is actually smaller than an enum, you should be OK to do

```
mOperation = reinterpret_cast<ENUM>(user_data);
```

The client has already gone into dubious areas when he's cast the enum into a void *, and that cast isn't going to make it any worse.

Comment: It's not me!  ; p I am just an innocent victim of the state of matters and have to cope with it somehow. I know this is ugly! Also you are wrong in "given that WSO_1 is in fact an enum, and I don't know of any platform where a void * is actually smaller than an enum, you should be OK" - this is actually my problem that void* can be greater than ENUM

Comment: @AB_ You have control of `handler` though judging from the question

Comment: I cannot change it's signature

Comment: the double casting is not required by the signature.

Comment: It is not my code, I know this is wrong. It has to be void* and I have to cast it to ENUM. How to write it safely, so I can check if the void* argument fits actually in ENUM

Comment: see my answer. anyone who passes your handler something that is not one of these enumeration values is invoking undefined behaviour, and they're broken before they get to you.

Incidentally, they could have passed a negative number as well.

Comment: You are wrong. It is not UB until you try to cast it to result that won't be feasible to contain it

Comment: they are passing you a 'xxxx' when you expect an ENUM. If the interface was typed like that, it'd be undefined behaviour anyway.
You should use an inptr_t, but check it's in range *properly*. They're breaking the contract if they pass that's not an ENUM so you can do what you want

Comment: The point is even if they meet contract and they are passing enum, on some implementations void* is wider than int, so you can't cast void* to int, and reinterpret_cast<ENUM> is UB

Comment: it's only UB if the enum has values that can't be fitted in a void * (i.e. a void * is narrower than an int). If a void * is wider than an int, then you'll be throwing away zero bits, exactly as you would if you cast an intptr_t to the enum

Comment: No. C Standard n1124 § 6.3.2.3 Pointers "If the result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is undefined. "

Comment: how big is WSO_COUNT?

Comment: doesn't matter, but we should assume at some point it may not fit in 2 bytes

Comment: TBH I think you're doomed anyway if any of your enum values is a trap representation for a pointer (though the standard is  unclear on that subject)